# Mismatched input 'STRING' expecting : near 'name' in column specification

Tags: hive

I am getting this error for the below code:

```
FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:111 mismatched input 'STRING' expecting : near 'name' in column specification

CREATE TABLE country2 
(name string, 
states ARRAY<STRING>,
cities_and_size MAP<STRING, INT>, 
parties STRUCT<name STRING, votes FLOAT, members INT>
)  
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'  
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\002'  
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\003'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
STORED AS TextFile;
```

Please help if you have any suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For STRUCT types, the field and datatype should be colon(:) separated.

So you query will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE country2 
(name string, 
states ARRAY<STRING>,
cities_and_size MAP<STRING, INT>, 
parties STRUCT<name:STRING, votes:FLOAT, members:INT>
)  
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'  
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\002'  
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\003'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
STORED AS TextFile;
```

Hope this helps...!!!